# Magento 2: Upgrading from CE to EE

Tags: magento2

I found a handful of posts that talked about upgrading Magento 1.x from CE to EE, but nothing about Magento 2. Currently, we are on Magento 1.9 and ultimately will be on Magento 2 EE. While I wait for budget etc; I wanted to start at the very least creating themes and setting up the basic configuration.

Are Magento 2 CE themes compatible with EE?
Is there an upgrade path that keeps store settings?
Is it possible to upgrade from CE to EE after I migrate 1.9 data?

I will likely do all this upgrading without modules, since thats obviously going to be the major pain point. Is there anything else I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving from Magento 2 CE to Magento 2 EE should be very straightforward. 2.0 EE literally consists of a bunch of addon modules that sit on top of CE. You won't lose any data, and almost all modules and customizations should be compatible with both CE and EE.

At a basic level, that means:

1. Upload EE files over what you have for your Magento 2 version.
2. Run in SSH: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. Test and verify

If you're running a custom theme, you may have to make changes to account for the EE additions.

Step 1 will vary depending on how you originally installed M2 CE. If you used the download package, you'll just need to download the package for EE and then upload those files.

If you used Composer, you'll need to get the keys for the appropriate Magento Connect account, and then change your composer setup to pull the Magento EE project. This is covered for fresh installs in the docs here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html#integrator-first-composer-ee -For the change, you'll need to switch from `magento/product-community-edition` to `magento/product-enterprise-edition`.

Comment: See also [this topic](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/upgrader/ce-ee-upgrade-start.html)